# Using transcations and parameters in ADO in VBScript

Tags: ms-access, parameters, transactions, vbscript, ado

I'm a bit stuck with parameters and transactions in ADO, in VBScript and Access. Basically, I'm working through a massive loop and writing the results to a database, so I need to wrap it in a transaction otherwise it takes ages.

I've written the below script which works for a single parameter, (although this seems a bit of a long way of doing it, so if anyone knows a shorter way, please shout). However I can't work out how to expand this to two parameters:

```
objConn.BeginTrans  

  set oParm = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
    oParm.Value = ""
    oParm.Type = 200
    oParm.Direction = 1
    oParm.Size = 100

  Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
    oCmd.commandText = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (?)"
    oCmd.commandType = 1
    oCmd.Parameters.Append oParm


    'Big loop here that goes through lots of lines.

      oCmd.Execute ,"Field",1

    'Loop 

objConn.CommitTrans
```

For example, if I wanted to expand this to:

```
oCmd.commandText = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (?,?)"
```

I can't figure out what I do with my parameters. I'm sure I'm just being stupid here and not quite following how these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried passing parameter values through the `Execute` method, so I can't quite say what's wrong.  I will say that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28VS.85%29.aspx) states that the second argument should be an *array* of values, so maybe if you tried `Array("Field1Val", "Field2Val")`, that would work.

What I usually do is give each parameter a name, then you can reference it within your loop to change its value.  You can use any name you like, as long each parameter has a unique name.  As an example:

```
' Sometime before your loop
oParm.Name = "foobar"

' Start loop
    oCmd.Parameters("foobar").Value = "someValue"
    oCmd.Execute , , 1
' End loop
```

---

As far as shortening the code, the only suggestion I can make is using the [`CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28VS.85%29.aspx) method to, well, create the parameter.  That will allow you to set all the relevant properties on one line.

```
Set oParm = oCmd.CreateParameter("foobar", 200, 1, 100)
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic. That's really pointed me in the right direction. Thanks so much.